# Force font awesome icon to fill div container

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to make the icon fill the div. I have tried using the fa classes(ex. fa-lg) but it makes the div box larger. I would like to keep the div box the same size but simply let the icon itself fill more of the box.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
      <td width="2%">
        <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://google.com"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i></a></div>
      </td>
      <td>
         TIME - <b>Location</b> - Address
      </td>
</tr><br />
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzwpovqq/)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the icon size by changing the font size of the same

```
.large {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Fiidle
https://jsfiddle.net/u0v9teLr/